# SFML networking and me (C++)

Tags: c++, networking, sfml

I think you guys are familiar with SFML? SFML has served me well in making games and other applications but I am wondering if it's worth it to apply it in networking? Like if I were to make a packet sniffer out of SFML, would this be a stupid choice since SFML was not intended for such things.

Comment: "stupid" is a value judgment that doesn't help us write better code. It makes more sense to say that SFML is *inappropriate* here, since it doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: If you are going to ask about a particular technology/library that is not universally used, you should add some link or reference so that people that are not familiar with it can at least browse over the docs.

Comment: I'm surprised that this question was closed. It was badly written but that didn't prevent us from arriving at a clear and definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question that is best answered by browsing [SFML's documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/). It looks like [Packet](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Packet.php), [SocketTCP](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1SocketTCP.php) and [SocketUDP](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1SocketUDP.php) are the relevant classes, but none of them appear to provide any functionality that would let you put your NIC into [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode).

A better starting point would be [`libpcap`](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: Why is their so many libs for C++? I mean I am not trying to be rude or a jerk but it seems like their is a libary for everything, and I am just asking why? I mean I thought their would be many libs, but they share the same field aka networking. Just wondering, and btw thanks for the answer!

Comment: Fair question. C++ has been around for a long time, and C even longer. For the most part, C libraries will work just fine with C++. So you've got a long time over which the two languages have been active. Over that time, lots of people have attempted to solve programming problems. There is some duplication, but sometimes people are introducing a new paradigm in their solution. Other languages have lots of libraries too - look at Java, for example.

Comment: Ah alright thanks man enjoy your top answer :)